# Pyomo Concrete model with csv

Tags: python, pandas, pyomo

I have a file with timesets and files with data at every timestep

Can someone tell me how to insert data from csv to parameters of concrete model of pyomo either by pandas or csv reader ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define sets and parameters from csv file to be used in pyomo optimization max quantity waste collected problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576493/define-sets-and-parameters-from-csv-file-to-be-used-in-pyomo-optimization-max-qu)

Comment: take a look at this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576493/define-sets-and-parameters-from-csv-file-to-be-used-in-pyomo-optimization-max-qu/71577962#71577962